# How to connect multiple QShortcuts to one slot in Qt? And find out inside the slot which shortcut emitted it?

Tags: qt, signals, signals-slots

Is it possible to pass parameters?

Something like this:

1. shortcut_key_one, channelSLot(int)
2. shortcut_key_two, channelSLot(int)
3. shortcut_key_three, channelSLot(int)

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't matter what the shortcut was, assign the shortcuts to a `QAction` using `QAction::setShortcuts`.

```
font_increase_action_ = new QAction(tr("&Increase font sizes"), this);
font_increase_action_->setShortcuts(QList<QKeySequence>()
                                    << Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_BracketRight
                                    << Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_Greater);
connect(font_increase_action_, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(IncreaseFontSizes()));
```

If you *really* need to know which shortcut was pressed, you could assign each one to a separate QAction and then use the [QSignalMapper](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do *exactly* what you're asking, you could keep track of all of your QShortcut objects and then use the sender() function inside of your slot to determine which QShortcut caused the slot to be triggered.

However, it sounds like you seriously want to consider using and overriding `QWidget::keyPressEvent()` instead if at all possible. It would be a lot easier to ask the QKeyEvent object which key was pressed than to do all this crazy QShortcut mess.